# Как сложить и вывести пользователю данные из списка словарей с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: python, json, list, telebot, словари

С помощью json получил список со словарями. В урезанном виде он выглядит так:

> [{'id':123, 'name': 'vase', 'pay': 1000},{'id':123, 'name': 'vase',
> 'pay': 1000}, {'id':222, 'name': 'phone', 'pay': 3000}]

Как сделать так, чтобы вывести пользователю сумму, исходя из нескольких условий, к примеру, если `id` и `name` одинаковый, то пользователю должна вывестись сумма **2000** (она получилась из сложений значений `pay`)

Чтобы просто вывести пользователю значения, я использую следующее:

```
res = requests.get(URL_INCOMES, params=params).json()
for i in res:
    id = i['id']
    name = i['name']
    pay = i['pay']
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Номер {id}\n Имя {name}\n Стоимость {pay}')
```

Список получается большой, много различных данных. Иногда нужно получить сумму  из трех или даже четырех одинаковых значений из списка и выдать ее пользователю.

Comment: Можете расПандить список и упростить себе задачу. (Pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Список словарей для примера:**

```
dictionaries = [{'id': 123, 'name': 'vase', 'pay': 1000},
                {'id': 222, 'name': 'phone', 'pay': 3000},
                {'id': 123, 'name': 'vase', 'pay': 500},
                {'id': 304, 'name': 'table', 'pay': 1200},
                {'id': 117, 'name': 'phone', 'pay': 3000},
                {'id': 183, 'name': 'bottle', 'pay': 3000},
                {'id': 304, 'name': 'table', 'pay': 700},
                {'id': 304, 'name': 'table', 'pay': 1000},
                {'id': 222, 'name': 'phone', 'pay': 3500},
                {'id': 222, 'name': 'ball', 'pay': 333}]
```

**Код:**

```
id_list, name_list, dict_numbers = [], [], []
for i in dictionaries:
    id_list.append(i['id'])
    name_list.append(i['name'])

for i, j in zip(enumerate(id_list), enumerate(name_list)):
    if id_list.count(i[1]) > 1 and name_list.count(j[1]) > 1:
        dict_numbers.append(i[0])

print(id_list, name_list, dict_numbers )
user_payment = 0
for i in dict_numbers:
    user_payment += dictionaries[i]['pay']
print(user_payment)
```

**Вывод:**

```
10900
```

**Вариант с разделением сумм по товарам:**

```
id_name_list = [f"Номер: {str(i['id'])}\nИмя: {i['name']}" for i in dictionaries]

result_dict = {}
for _, i in enumerate(id_name_list):
    if id_name_list.count(i) > 1:
        if result_dict.get(i):
            result_dict[i] += dictionaries[_]['pay']
        else:
            result_dict[i] = dictionaries[_]['pay']

for j in result_dict:
    print(f'{j}\nСтоимость: {result_dict[j]}')
```

**Вывод этого варианта:**

```
Номер: 123
Имя: vase
Стоимость: 1500
Номер: 222
Имя: phone
Стоимость: 6500
Номер: 304
Имя: table
Стоимость: 2900
```

Comment: ['nm_id': 117407570, 'doc_type_name': 'Продажа', 'ppvz_for_pay': 0}, {'nm_id': 117407570, 'doc_type_name': 'Продажа', 'ppvz_for_pay': 1431.04}, {'nm_id': 117407570, 'doc_type_name': 'Продажа', 'ppvz_for_pay': 0}, { 'nm_id': 117238394, 'doc_type_name': 'Продажа', 'ppvz_for_pay': 1654.64}, {'nm_id': 117238394,  'doc_type_name': 'Продажа', 'ppvz_for_pay': 0}] вот мой словарь. Переписал ваш код под свои значения, user_payment он посчитал, но не зависимо от nm_id. Т.е. он сложил ppvz_for_pay из разных nm_id, а хотелось бы только из одинаковых. И если nm_id будет несколько, то чтобы сложил несколько

Comment: @Vladimir я добавил в ответ вариант с разделением суммы по товарам